# Running time of BFS vs. Dijkstra's, values don't make sense

Tags: c++, list, matrix, dijkstra, breadth-first-search

I'm doing a comparison of Dijkstra's and BFS, on both adjacency lists and adjacency matrices. I'm testing all four variations as shortest path algorithms, and clocking their running time over unweighted graphs that go from sparse to dense.

My understanding is that adjacency lists should perform better (i.e., have a faster clock time) on sparse graphs, and as the graph gets denser the matrix will eventually become the faster implementation. However, when I run my code the matrices always out-perform the lists, and I cannot for the life of me understand why. Any insight would be incredibly appreciated.

//main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Graph.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //struct timeval begin, finish;

    int numVertices = 10;

    //Calculate the maximum number of edges that can exist in an undirected graph
    int maxNumEdges = (numVertices*(numVertices-1))/2;
    cout << "maxNumEdges" << maxNumEdges << endl;

    //Run all the algorithms with increasing number of edges
    for(int i = 0; i < maxNumEdges; i++) {
        int numEdges = i;
        Graph g(numVertices);
        cout <<  "Number of edges: " << numEdges << endl;

        g.generate(numEdges);
        int destination = g.getDestination();

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        g.adjListBFS(0, destination);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end1= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        g.matrixBFS(0, destination);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end2= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();


        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        g.dijkstraList(0, destination);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end3= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();


        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin4 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        g.dijkstraMatrix(0, destination);
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end4= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        //cout << endl;

        cout << "BfSList Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end1 - begin1).count() << " ";
        cout << "BFS Matrix Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2 - begin2).count() << " ";
        cout << "DijList Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end3 - begin3).count() << " ";
        cout << "DijMatrix Time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end4 - begin4).count() << " ";
        cout << endl;

        //break;

    }

}
```

//Graph.cpp

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <list> 
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Constructor
Graph::Graph(int numV) {
    numVertices = numV;

    //intialize vertex array
    vertexArray = new int[numVertices];
    //Initialize adjacency list
    adjList = new list<int>[numVertices];
    //Initialize matrix
    matrix = new int*[numVertices];
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[numVertices];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = 0;   
        }
    }
}


//Generate a random graph
void Graph::generate(int numEdges) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int currentEdges = 0;
    int v1 = rand() % numVertices-1;

    //Pick destination vertex. If 0 randomly generated, just add 1 to it
    int dest = rand() % numVertices;
    if (dest != 0) {
        destination = dest;
    } else {
        destination = 1;
    }

    while(currentEdges < numEdges) {
        //cout << "stuck in generate while" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
            //cout << "Stuck in first for loop" << endl;
            v1 = rand() % numVertices;
            if (edgeExists(i, v1) == true || i == v1) {
                //cout << "hit if" << endl;
                //i--;
            } else {
                adjList[i].push_back(v1);
                adjList[v1].push_back(i);
                matrix[i][v1] == 1;
                matrix[v1][i] == 1;
                currentEdges++;
                //cout << "Hit else" << endl;
            //cout << "Added " << i << " to " << v1 << " list" << endl;
            //cout << "Added " << v1 << " to " << i << " list" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}


//Checking to be sure edge is not added twice
bool Graph::edgeExists(int v1, int v2) {
    bool alreadyAdded = false;
    for(list<int>::iterator i = adjList[v1].begin(); i != adjList[v1].end(); ++i) {
        //cout << "(*i): " << (*i) << " v2: " << v2 << endl;
        if(*i == v2) {
            alreadyAdded = true;
        } 
    }
    return alreadyAdded;
}

//In list already - make sure correct number of vertices are created
bool Graph::inList(int v1) {
    bool check = false;
    for(vector<int>::iterator i = vectorVertex.begin(); i != vectorVertex.end(); ++i) {
        if((*i) == v1) {
            check = true;
        }   
    }
    return check;
}

//================================================BFS with adjacency list====================================================
void Graph::adjListBFS(int s, int e){ 
    int nodesVisited = 0;
    bool foundDest = false;
    bool *visited = new bool[numVertices];
    int *previous = new int[numVertices];
    int start = s;
    int dest = e;

    //Initialize vertices to 'not visited'
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    //Create a queue, push starting vertex on
    queue<int> Q;
    visited[s] = true;
    Q.push(s);
    //cout << "BFS complete traversal: ";

    while(!Q.empty() && foundDest == false) {
            s = Q.front();
            Q.pop();
        //  cout << s << " -> ";
            nodesVisited++;
            for(list<int>::iterator i = adjList[s].begin(); i != adjList[s].end(); ++i) {
                if(!visited[*i]) {
                    visited[(*i)] = true;
                    Q.push(*i);
                    previous[(*i)] = s;

                    if((*i) == e) {
                        foundDest = true;
                        //cout << e << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                } 
            }
     }
    vector<int> pathVector;
    //bool check = false;
    //printPath(previous, e);
    //cout << "Backwards path: " << e << " <- ";
   /*   for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        cout << previous[e] << " <- ";
        if(previous[e] == start) {
            break;
        } else {
            e = previous[e];
        }
    }*/

    /*pathVector.push_back(start);
    for(vector<int>::iterator i = pathVector.end(); i != pathVector.begin(); --i) {
        cout << pathVector.at(*i) << " -> ->  " ;
    }*/

    //cout << endl;
            //  cout << "stuck in BFS adjlist" << endl;

}

//====================================================BFS with Matrix===========================================================


void Graph::matrixBFS(int s, int e){ 
    bool foundDest = false;
    bool *visited = new bool[numVertices];

    //Initialize vertices to 'not visited'
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    //Create a queue, push starting vertex on
    queue<int> Q;
    visited[s] = true;
    Q.push(s);

    //While there are still vertices to process
     while(!Q.empty() && foundDest == false) {
            s = Q.front();
            Q.pop();
            //cout << s << " -> ";

            for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
                if(matrix[i][s] == 1 && visited[i] == false) {
                    visited[i] = true;
                    Q.push(i);
                } 
                if(s == e) {
                foundDest = true;
                break;
            }
            }
     }
    //cout << endl;


}

//For reconstructing the path 
void Graph::printPath(int parent[], int j) {
    if (parent[j] == -1) {
        return;
    }

    printPath(parent, parent[j]);
    //cout << j << "->" << endl;
    //cout << " ";
}



//======================================================Dijkstra Matrix============================================================
void Graph::dijkstraMatrix(int s, int e) {
    bool foundDest = false;
    int infinity = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int distance[numVertices];
    bool visited[numVertices];
    int parent[numVertices];

    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        parent[i] = -1;
        distance[i] = infinity;
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    //Distance from starting vertex to itself is 0
    distance[s] = 0;

    //Create a queue, push first element on
    queue<int> dijQueue;
    dijQueue.push(s);

    while(!dijQueue.empty() && foundDest == false) {
        int current = dijQueue.front();
        dijQueue.pop();
        visited[current] = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
                if(!visited[i] && matrix[current][i] && distance[current]+matrix[s][i] < distance[i]) {
                    parent[i] = current;
                    distance[i] = distance[current] + 1;
                    if(s == e) {
                        foundDest = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    dijQueue.push(i);
                }
            }   
    }

/*  int startVertex = 0;
    //cout << "Path" << " " << "Vertex" << " " << "Distance" << endl;
    for (int i= 1; i < numVertices; i++) {
        printPath(parent, i);
        //cout << "    " << startVertex << "-->" << i << "   " << "        " << endl;   
    }*/
                    //  cout << "stuck in Dijkstra Matrix" << endl;

}

//==================================================Dijkstra Adjacency List============================================================
void Graph::dijkstraList(int s, int e) {
    bool foundDest = false;
    int infinity = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int distance[numVertices];
    bool visited[numVertices];
    int parent[numVertices];

    //Initialize
    for(int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
        parent[i] = -1;
        distance[i] = infinity;
        visited[i] = false;
    }

    //Distance from starting vertex to itself is 0
    distance[s] = 0;

    //Create a queue, push first element on
    queue<int> dijQueue;
    dijQueue.push(s);

    //While there are still vertexes to process
    while(!dijQueue.empty() && foundDest == false) {
        int current = dijQueue.front();
        dijQueue.pop();
        visited[current] = true;

            //cout << "current: " << current << endl;

        for(list<int>::iterator i = adjList[current].begin(); i != adjList[current].end(); ++i) {

            if(!visited[*i] && (distance[current]+1) < distance[*i]) {
                parent[*i] = current;
                distance[*i] = distance[current] + 1;
                if(s == e) {
                    foundDest = true;
                    break;
                }
                dijQueue.push(*i);
            }
        }
    }

    //Print results
    int startVertex = 0;
    //cout << startVertex << " ";
    //printPath(parent, e);
                            //cout << "stuck in Dijkstra List" << endl;


}

//Returns the "ending" vertex that was randomly generated
int Graph::getDestination() {
    return destination;
}
```

//Graph.h

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H_
#define GRAPH_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Graph {

    private:
        int numVertices;
        list<int> *adjList;
        int *vertexArray;
        int **matrix;
        vector<int> vectorVertex;


    public: 
        int destination;
        int currentNumVertices;
        Graph(int numV);
        void generate(int numEdges);
        int getDestination();

        bool inList(int v1);
        bool edgeExists(int v1, int v2);
        void adjListBFS(int s, int e);
        void matrixBFS(int s, int e);
        void dijkstraMatrix(int s, int e);
        void dijkstraList(int s, int e);

        void printPath(int parent[], int j);

};

#endif
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` in `Graph::generate` is potentially dangerous. Every call to generate will reseed the random number generator, and if it is called twice within 1 second, the minimum resolution of `time`, you will get the exact same generated values from `rand`. Typical usage of `srand` is to call it once early in `main` and then leave it alone. And while we are here, consider using [C++11's random library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). it can provide much better results

Comment: And watch out for these: `int distance[numVertices]` this is what's called a Variable Length Array. They are not a part of Standard C++ and are not supported on many compilers, Visual Studio being one of the bigger names.

Comment: `Graph` class lacks a destructor and leaks memory. This hides a [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) violation that might bite you later.

Comment: On topic, finally, [may I recommend gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/) to find out where all your time is going and possibly help you narrow down your search?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are making comparisons instead of assignments here:

```
matrix[i][v1] == 1;
matrix[v1][i] == 1;
```

That should be `=` not `==`.

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I missed that. After making that change I still seem to be getting inconsistent values, though. My matrices now perform worse than the list as the graph gets denser, even when I generate a graphs of 100 vertices. Could anything else be the problem?